# Different character after export application on Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

When I run my application on Eclipse, I can see the correct latin character, like this:

[image]

But when I export to runnable jar file and execute it, the special character is wrong, like this:

[image]

I have no idea why this happen. On Mac it's ok both on Eclipse and .jar file. But on Windows it's not ok.

I get the data from webserver and I show in a JavaFX ListView.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a String turned into UTF-8 bytes shown as some Windows encoding.

My guess you did this:

```
URL url = ...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream());
```

Whereas you should have done this:

```
URL url = ...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(),
                              StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

The constructor InputStreamReader without Charset will use the current default platform encoding - wrong.

For *any* URL you could first do an [`openConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) and try to divine the delivered encoding. The strategy is a bit circumstantial:

- connection.getContentEncoding() / getContentType
- default is ISO-8859-1
- When ISO-8859-1 take Windows-1252 instead, as browser do that too

Java keeps Unicode in `String, char`, so all scripts can be handled simultaneous.

Binary data, `byte[], InputStream, OutputStream`, need to have the charset/encoding specified, when it must be converted from/to text.

Comment: Thank you so much @Joop Eggen. Now it's work perfectly